# NameError while trying to extend a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I am trying to make a pokemon game. In this game, I am trying to have pokemon (specific ) classes, which extend a pokemon class(general)

for example, Charmander class extends the pokemon class

However, whenever I extend the pokemon, I get a name error, I tried importing pokemon before extending it, and I still got an error
This is my pokemon.py:

```
from Charmander import *
from Bulbasaur import *
from Turtwig import *
class Pokemon:
    def __init__(self, current_hp, attack, defense):
        self.name = "PlaceHolder"
        self.pokemon_type = "PlaceHolder"
        self.current_hp = current_hp
        self.attack = attack
        self.defense = defense
        self.fainted = False

    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    def getType(self):
        return self.pokemon_type

    def getCurrentHP(self):
        return self.current_hp

    def getHealth(self):
        return self.current_hp

    def getAttack(self):
        return self.attack

    def getDefense(self):
        return self.defense

    def getFainted(self):
        return self.fainted

    def printStatus(self):
        print(self.name)
        print(str(self.current_hp))
    def takedamage(self, amount):
        self.current_hp -= amount
    def tackle(self, opponent):
        opponent.current_hp -= self.attack

    def die(self, opponent):
        self.fainted = True
        if self.current_hp == 0:
            print("You Lose!")
        elif(opponent.current_hp == 0):
            print("You win!")

    def checkDead(self, opponent):
        if self.current_hp == 0 or opponent.current_hp == 0:
            self.die(opponent)

    def assignPokemon(self, player):
        if player == "Charmander":
            player = Charmander(200, 20, 20)
        if player == "Bulbasaur":
            player = Bulbasaur(200, 20, 20)
        if player == "Turtwig":
            player = Turtwig(200, 20, 20)
        return player
```

This is my Charmander.py:

```
from pokemon import *
class Charmander(Pokemon):
    pass
    def __init__(self, current_hp, attack, defense):
        self.name = "Charmander"
        self.type = "Fire"
        self.current_hp = 200
        self.attack = 10
        self.defense = 10

    def ember(self, opponent):
        opponent.takeDamage(40)

    def will_o_wisp(self, opponent):
        return

    def flamethrower(self, opponent):
        opponent.takeDamage(90)
```

This is the error I am receiving: 
/Users/alex/PycharmProjects/test/venv/bin/python "/Users/alex/Documents/SCSNoonan Computer Science/Slow Pokemon/main.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alex/Documents/SCSNoonan Computer Science/Slow Pokemon/main.py", line 1, in 
    from pokemon import *
  File "/Users/alex/Documents/SCSNoonan Computer Science/Slow Pokemon/pokemon.py", line 1, in 
    from Charmander import *
  File "/Users/alex/Documents/SCSNoonan Computer Science/Slow Pokemon/Charmander.py", line 2, in 
    class Charmander(Pokemon):
NameError: name 'Pokemon' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is probably due to [circular imports](http://stackabuse.com/python-circular-imports/). Also, the `pass` statement before your `__init__` method inside your `Charmander` class is useless.

You don't need to do this in your `pokemon.py` file

```
from Charmander import *
from Bulbasaur import *
from Turtwig import *
```

The method `assignPokemon` doesn't need `self` parameter so it should either be a `staticmethod` or be outside of your `Pokemon` class.

You should put all pokemon classes in a file together and then you could call `assignPokemon` in another file, for example:

```
# main.py
from pokemon import Charmander, Bulbasaur, Turtwig

def assignPokemon(player):
    if player == "Charmander":
        player = Charmander(200, 20, 20)
    if player == "Bulbasaur":
        player = Bulbasaur(200, 20, 20)
    if player == "Turtwig":
        player = Turtwig(200, 20, 20)
    return player
```

Comment: That `pass` doesn't do anything. It's pointless, but it isn't the cause of the problem.

Comment: Thank you, I removed the *pass*